# Uknown CMake Command "catkin_package"

Tags: ros, catkin-package, ros-fuerte, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This CMakeLists.txt File

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(ardrone_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
catkin_package()

install(PROGRAMS
src/drone_controller.py         
src/drone_status.py         
src/drone_video_display.py          
src/joystick_controller.py          
src/keyboard_controller.py
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION} )

install(DIRECTORY launch/  
DESTINATION
${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
)
```

Gives the results

```
rosmake starting...                   
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are:
['ardrone_tutorials']                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory
/home/ardrone/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160628-151821
[ rosmake ] Expanded args
['ardrone_tutorials'] to:
['ardrone_tutorials']       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [
make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No
Makefile in package roslang           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make
]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No
Makefile in package roscpp            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs
[ make ]                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs
No Makefile in package geometry_msgs  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [
make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs 
No Makefile in package sensor_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [
make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No
Makefile in package rosbuild          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make
]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No
Makefile in package roslib            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [
make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole 
No Makefile in package rosconsole     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [
make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib
ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>>
message_filters [ make ]              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<<
message_filters  No Makefile in
package message_filters [rosmake-0]
Starting >>> image_transport [ make ] 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<<
image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package
image_transport  [rosmake-0] Starting
>>> std_srvs [ make ]                                       [rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs  No
Makefile in package std_srvs          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make
]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet
ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make
]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles
ROS_NOBUILD in package angles         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make
]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No
Makefile in package rospy             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [
make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No
Makefile in package rostest           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make
]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No
Makefile in package roswtf            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf
ROS_NOBUILD in package tf             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>>
common_rosdeps [ make ]               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<<
common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package
common_rosdeps    [rosmake-0] Starting
>>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                     [rosmake-0]
Finished <<<
camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD
in package camera_calibration_parsers
[rosmake-0] Starting >>>
camera_info_manager [ make ]          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<<
camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in
package camera_info_manager
[rosmake-0] Starting >>>
ardrone_autonomy [ make ]             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<<
ardrone_autonomy [PASS] [ 4.55 seconds
]                [rosmake-0] Starting
>>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                [rosmake-0] Finished <<<
diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in
package diagnostic_msgs [rosmake-0]
Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No
Makefile in package std_msgs          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>>
diagnostic_updater [ make ]           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<<
diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in
package diagnostic_updater [rosmake-0]
Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No
Makefile in package rosbag            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> joy [ make ] 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< joy
ROS_NOBUILD in package joy            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>>
ardrone_tutorials [ make ]            
[ rosmake ] All 9
linesardrone_tutorials: 0.2 sec ]  [ 1
Active 26/27 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------   mkdir -p bin   cd build && cmake -Wdev
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..  
TODO: implement add_roslaunch_check()
in rostest-extras.cmake.   CMake Error
at CMakeLists.txt:5 (catkin_package):
    Unknown CMake command "catkin_package".
  
     -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of
package ardrone_tutorials written to:
[ rosmake ]   
/home/ardrone/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160628-151821/ardrone_tutorials/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<<
ardrone_tutorials [FAIL] [ 0.25
seconds ]               [ rosmake ]
Halting due to failure in package
ardrone_tutorials.  [ rosmake ]
Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                  
[ rosmake ] Built 27 packages with 1
failures.                             
[ rosmake ] Summary output to
directory                             
[ rosmake ]
/home/ardrone/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160628-151821
```

Any idea why the CMake Error happens? The find_package(catkin) was in the line before catkin_package(), so I don't know waht else is needed. The catkin package is also under the share folder in the opt/ros/fuerte directory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238273/uknown-cmake-command-%22catkin_package%22/) by [moisesm54](https://answers.ros.org/users/27319/moisesm54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like you have a CMakeLists.txt file for the `catkin` build system, but you are trying to build the package using the command `rosmake` (from the old `rosbuild` system). That won't work. If you are on Fuerte and using `rosmake`, you'll need an old style manifest.xml (instead of package.xml) and CMakeLists.txt.

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild/CMakeLists

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild/Manifest

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-06-28**:
Yes, you should not use catkin in Fuerte. Please see the first note on the catkin wiki page for Fuerte: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin?distro=fuerte